# Copy (or list) files of a remote folder, given the URL - using objective-c - is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, list, url, file

I'd like to list all files from a remote folder (let's say www.mysite.com/folder, and this folder is already configured through .htaccess for directory listing).

After listing, i'll need to copy the remote files to a local folder.

For listing/copying only local files, I was using NSFileManager, but this doesn't work for the remote ones. I've been looking for some reference on it, but couldn't find so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best way, but - instead of get directory listing - we're going to keep a list of files that should be transfered (could be a .txt or .xml).

For downloading and tracking multiple requests, we're going to use ASINetworkQueues (more details can be found on http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest).

---

Another good suggestion, given by [d11wqt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322122/d11wtq) (thank you for your help), is compressing the files and just make one single request.

Answer (score 1):

While NSFileManager can in fact handle URLs, it's not going to download the apache HTML page with the directory listing and parse it to do this... you'll have to do that yourself.  This sounds like a strange thing to be doing however, so you may want to explain the reasoning and we may be able to suggest better alternatives.  [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) comes to mind.

UPDATE: Based on your comment, why not put the resources in a .zip (or similar) file and download that?  Then it's a single download and you can just extract it locally.  Sounds like it would save a lot of headaches and would make it much easier to do things like checksum validations on the download(s).

Comment: I'm trying to copy all the files of the remote folder to the local app Documents (in my case, they're some resources that need to be updated when the application launches). I can use [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url], but for this I would need to know the name of each file in the remote folder (which may change).

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion.  In short, I think you're going down the wrong path.  The apache directory listing is not intended for programmatic use.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, man. I agree that this would be helpful, but in my specific case, a .zip would be hard to maintain on the user side.