# Swift - Listing contents of a non-local directory

Tags: swift, file, url, directory, nsfilemanager

I'd like to list the contents of an external directory in Swift 2. It seems easy enough for a local directory, but I just can't figure it out with an external directory. Here is my code:

```
var theUrlString = "https://great-castles.com/images/berkeley/"
var theUrl = NSURL(string: theUrlString)!

do {
  let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(theUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
  print(directoryContents)

} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

In the playground, I am getting the error:
`The file “berkeley” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file`

Note that I just threw a random URL in there as an example. But [it is accessible](https://great-castles.com/images/berkeley/), so I should be able to get a list of the files, right? Does NSFileManager.defaultManager think I am referring to a local file?

What I'd really like to do is copy the contents of an online directory into the document directory on the device. If the above isn't possible, any ideas on the best way to do that?

Comment: NSFileManager does not handle remote files or folders: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567711/get-all-folders-of-url or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267517/copy-or-list-files-of-a-remote-folder-given-the-url-using-objective-c-is.

Comment: Thanks! Those links are really helpful. It looks like the problem is that the remote directory isn't actually working like a filesystem, it is returning an html file listing its contents, which NSFileManager can't parse. I like the ideas of using FTP or putting everything into a single archive.